# How can I receive an email alert when a particular PC is not running?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, monitoring

At my office I have a Windows XP PC that is always supposed to be running and logged in,  because it is used as a server.

Is there an existing app that would allow me to get an automated email alert whenever this PC isn’t running and logged in? Perhaps the server PC would send a signal to a remote PC on an hourly basis, and if this signal isn't received, then an email alert would be generated.

LogMeIn Pro has a feature that can accomplish this, but I would prefer a free option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php/), according to the [online manual](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Email_notifications), can send email notifications.